# Mobile Facebook Friends List Get All

Tags: facebook, pagination

In mobile the url used to view all friends is http://m.facebook.com/friends/?refid=5. But facebook has pagination and I want to see the list with all my friends. I even tried using parameters like this :
http://m.facebook.com/friends/?start=A&end=Z&pa&refid=5 but this doesnt show the total friends as well... Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an integer parameter, limit.  I haven't tested it with the mobile interface, but for the regular graph, the list of friends has a controllable maximum size.  The URL looks like this: https://www.graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/friends?limit=5000.  You can play around with these URL's by using the Graph API Explorer tool on the facebook developer site.